# Splitting fields of polynomials over finite fields of prime-power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ is the finite field of size $p^k$, where $p$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer. Also $m$ is a positive integer such that $p \nmid m$, with $K$ being the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{m} − 1$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. I want to prove that $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ iff $p^{k} \equiv 1 \mod m$.

I have a hunch that it would useful to know $F = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ where $n$ is the smallest such integer such that $p^n \equiv 1 \mod m$, but I'm unsure of how to prove this, or how I would use it in the overall proof.

Comment: It seems the condition should be $p^m \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. The multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $p^m - 1$, so it contains an element of order $m$ if and only if $m$ divides $p^m - 1$. Or did you mean $K$ to be the splitting field of $x^m - 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $K$ is the splitting field of the polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$. I corrected my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F = \mathbb{F}_{p^k}, L = \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$. Then $K \subset L$ if and only if $F \subset L$ and $L^{\times}$ contains an element of order $m$.

$L^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $p^m - 1$ and thus contains an element of order $m$ if and only if $m$ divides $p^m - 1$.

Recall that there is a unique extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of any given degree, and if $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ is an extension of degree $n$, then for any $d$ dividing $n$ there is a subextension $E'$ of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Therefore we have $F \subset L$ if and only if $k = [F : \mathbb{F}_p]$ divides $m = [L : \mathbb{F}_p]$

So we have that $K$ is a subfield of $L$ if and only if $p^m \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ and $k \mid m$.

Note that your claimed condition implies that $F^{\times}$ contains an element of order $m$, which would imply that $K = F$.